# How to connect desktop application and browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

For example, I have a desktop application (for example, a high-performance calculator) and an asp mvc iis server, and a remote client uses a web browser.

1) How can I configure the interaction between the desktop application and the server? Can I use WCF for interprocess communication between the calculator and asp?

|calculator| <-? -> |IIS (ASP.NET MVC)| <-online-> |client (browser)|

2) How much will the performance impact if the application functionality is transferred to the server?

|IIS (ASP.NET MVC calculator)| <-Internet-> |client (browser)|

3) Is there a way to make requests from the browser to the application, for example (WCF + ajax)?

|calculator| <-? Internet-> |client (browser)|

Comment: It is rarely a good idea today to use WCF. SignalR is very simple to use as the bridge, and you can host it on IIS or use Azure SignalR service. Overall, your questions above are too broad. Besides SignalR you can find other options.

Comment: Moreover, this isn't really how the internet works. You'll need to pass identifiers back and forth to make sure you are talking to the correct browser/desktop application on both sides.

Answer (score 0):

To make it run on the client, your calculator would need to be implemented with javascript.

My approach would be to implement the calculator as a dotnet core microservice, and have the client code use jQuery to make an ajax request to that service.

You may need to add a wrapper method to the web application that calls the microservice if you can't update your routing to reach the microservice from outside.

Answer (score 0):

1) In the ASP.NET application you can call a dll as a library. This dll should have access to the backend of your calculator.

2) You should start an instance of your calculator for each user and keep it open based on some session. There is about 50-300ms of delay between every interaction. This should be compensated by having JS do some of the user interface animations and such.

3) Yes this 'ajax' is a XmlHttpRequest. A POST or GET request are two flavors of this kind of request for example. Basically you send plain text JSON data back and forth to a url on your webserver. Your webserver receives this in a controller in ASP.NET and does something with it, and responds. There are alternatives such as websockets but this is not a good place to start.